# Разница между NSTableView создаваемым IB и создаваемым в коде

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

Таблица, созданная средствами Interface Builder не отображала отдаваемые ей данные, и беглый гуглинг показал как альтернативу создание таблицы программно: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599747/programmatically-creating-an-nstableview-trouble-getting-the-nsheaderview-to-sh

Созданная таким образом, она отображала данные, которые отдавались тем же источником. Откуда такая разница?

Мой DataSource (оставался неизменным):

```
class BodyStorage:NSObject, NSTableViewDataSource {
var body_arr:[Body] = [Body]()
func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return body_arr.count
}
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> AnyObject? {

    switch tableColumn!.identifier {
    case "mass":
        return body_arr[row].mass
    case "speed_x":
        return body_arr[row].speed.x
    case "speed_y":
        return body_arr[row].speed.y
    case "position_x":
        return body_arr[row].position.x
    case "position_y":
        return body_arr[row].position.y
    default:
        return "oopsie"
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, setObjectValue object: AnyObject?, forTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) {
    switch tableColumn!.identifier {
    case "mass":
        body_arr[row].mass = (object as! NSString).doubleValue
    case "speed_x":
        body_arr[row].speed.x = (object as! NSString).doubleValue
    case "speed_y":
        body_arr[row].speed.y = (object as! NSString).doubleValue
    case "position_x":
        body_arr[row].position.x = (object as! NSString).doubleValue
    case "position_y":
        body_arr[row].position.y  = (object as! NSString).doubleValue
    default:
        print("Something went wrong")
    }
}
}
```

Код для создания таблицы:

```
let tableContainer = NSScrollView(frame:NSMakeRect(10, 10, window!.frame.width - 20, window!.frame.height - 40))
    let tableView = NSTableView(frame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, window!.frame.width - 20, window!.frame.height - 50))
    let column1 = NSTableColumn(identifier: "mass")
    let column2 = NSTableColumn(identifier: "speed_x")
    let column3 = NSTableColumn(identifier: "speed_y")
    let column4 = NSTableColumn(identifier: "position_x")
    let column5 = NSTableColumn(identifier: "position_y")
    column1.width = (window!.frame.width - 20)/5
    column2.width = (window!.frame.width - 20)/5
    column3.width = (window!.frame.width - 20)/5
    column4.width = (window!.frame.width - 20)/5
    column5.width = (window!.frame.width - 20)/5
    tableView.addTableColumn(column1)
    tableView.addTableColumn(column2)
    tableView.addTableColumn(column3)
    tableView.addTableColumn(column4)
    tableView.addTableColumn(column5)
    tableView.setDataSource(storage)
    tableView.reloadData()
    tableContainer.documentView = tableView
    tableContainer.hasVerticalScroller = true
    window?.contentView.addSubview(tableContainer)
```

Comment: быть может в IB не привязали data source?

Comment: @iFreeman привязал, он число строк делает нужное, но не заполняет данными, даже если функция возвращает в любом случае одно и то же значение.

Comment: @RomaValcer что значит "даже если функция возвращает в любом случае одно и тоже значение"? Delegate привязали? Как привязываете данные к ячейки? Cell Indentificator есть? Трудно сказать, что вы делаете не так, если нет куска кода или скриншотов.

Comment: @runia делегата я не привязывал, так как только учусь, и не разобрался с ними, "даже если функция возвращает в любом случае одно и тоже значение" - я имел ввиду, что даже если в функции `NSTableViewDataSource tableView(tableView: NSTableView, setObjectValue object: AnyObject?, forTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int)` делать сразу return("lol"), то ничего не отображается.

Answer (score 1):

судя по всему, вы назначили в IB datasource другой. Внимательно посмотрите, к чему привязали. Т.к. методы необязательные, то у того объекта, к которому вы привязали, таблица их не находит -> нет крэша. Поставьте в дебаге точку во viewDidLoad и проверьте кто является .dataSource у вашей таблицы. Им Должен быть self. Если нет - значит я прав.